# Sending HTML form data via XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, html

I try to send data from a HTML form via `XMLHttpRequest` to the server.
Problem is, on server side via PHP I can not access the data.

I always get back as `responseText`:

> Anfrage erhält keinen EntleiherLang --
>
> Anfrage erhält keinen StartDatum --
>
> Anfrage erhält keinen EndeDatum --

After sending the request if I look into the network analyse I see that the parameter send is set to

**[object HTMLFormElement]**

To me it seems that the line:

```
var formData = new FormData();
var formData = document.querySelector("#NeueDaten");
```

is not really putting form data into `FormData` format.

Here is the HTML side:

```js
  <script>  
   $('#NeueDaten').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log(xhttp.responseText);
     }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "NeueEntleihung.php", true);
    var formData = new FormData();
    var formData = document.querySelector("#NeueDaten");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Test","test2");
    xhttp.send(formData);
    });

  </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html style="background-image:none;">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/plain"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head> 
  <body style="width: 80%;padding: 5%; padding-top:0; margin:auto;">

  <form id="NeueDaten" name="foorm" action="">
   <input type="text" name="NeuerEntleiherLang">
   <input type="date" name="StartDatum" >   
   <input type="date" name="EndeDatum" >
   <input type="submit" name="SubmitButton">
  </form>
```

Here is PHP

```php
<?php

header("Content-type: text/HTML");

$responseText = '';
if(!isset($_POST['EntleiherLang'])) {
   $responseText = 'Anfrage erhält keinen EntleiherLang -- ';
} else {
   $responseText = "EntleiherLang: " .$_POST['EntleiherLang'] ." --" ;
}

if(!isset($_POST['StartDatum'])) {
   $responseText = $responseText.'Anfrage erhält keinen StartDatum --';
} else {
   $responseText = $responseText ."StartDatum: " .$_POST['StartDatum'] ." --" ;
}

if(!isset($_POST['EndeDatum'])) {
   $responseText = $responseText.'Anfrage erhält keinen EndeDatum -- ';
} else {
   $responseText = $responseText ."EndeDatum: " .$_POST['EndeDatum'] ." --" ;
}

header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' '.$responseStatus);
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo $responseText;

?>
```

Comment: you don't have a field named `EntleiherLang` in your html form - you do have `NeuerEntleiherLang` though and you never send the FormData

Comment: Thanks, but thats not the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the form element as argument in the FormData object:

```js
$('#NeueDaten').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log(xhttp.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "NeueEntleihung.php", true);
    var formData = new FormData(document.querySelector("#NeueDaten"));
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Test", "test2");
    xhttp.send(formData);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="NeueDaten" name="foorm" action="">
<input type="text" name="NeuerEntleiherLang">
<input type="date" name="StartDatum" >   
<input type="date" name="EndeDatum" >
<input type="submit" name="SubmitButton">
</form>
```

You could use jQuery to send the Ajax post, will be more readable and clean

Comment: THANK you verry much. It took me hours and you pointet the right direction.

Comment: And I changed to jQuerry as well

Comment: i'm glad to hear that @Humbarzel